# Ball in Brick Breaker game destroys whole lines without touching them(Java)

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I have been making a brick breaker game for fun, but I came across an odd error in the execution of the program. When the game is started, the ball is set in motion away from the bricks. However, it starts destroying them almost immediately, starting from the brick furthest to the right on the upper row and continuing to break them all from right to left. Then it goes to the second row and destroys them from left to right. This whole time, on the screen, the ball is away from any bricks.

I think I pinpointed the problem to the following piece of code. Here I create a rectangle around the ball and a rectangle around the brick and if they were to intersect, I call the method `setBrickValue` inside another class called `Map Generator`, which sets the value of the brick to 0, meaning, it doesn't exist.

Here's the method:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            timer.start();
            //makes sure the ball collides with the paddle
            if(play){
                if( new Rectangle( ballPositionX, ballPositionY, 20, 20)
                        .intersects( new Rectangle( player, 550, 100, 8 ) ) ){
                    ballDirY = - ballDirY;
                }
                // beginning of the code with an error in it, the rectangle around the ball
                //is intersecting incorrectly the rectangle of the brick
                A:for(int i = 0; i < MGobj.map.length; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < MGobj.map[0].length; j++){
                        if(MGobj.map [i] [j] > 0){
                            int brickX = i * MGobj.brickWidth + 80;
                            int brickY = j * MGobj.brickHeight + 50;
                            int brickWidth = MGobj.brickWidth;
                            int brickHeight = MGobj.brickHeight;

                            //create the rectangle around the brick
                            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle( brickX, brickY,
                                    brickWidth, brickHeight );

                            //create the rectangle around the ball, so we can detect the intersection
                            Rectangle ballRect = new Rectangle( ballPositionX, ballPositionY, 20, 20 );

                            Rectangle brickRect = rect;
                            //when intersecting, delete the brick off the map
                            if( ballRect.intersects( brickRect )){
                                MGobj.setBrickValue( 0, i, j );
                                totalBricks--;
                                score += 5;
                                //
                                if( ballPositionX + 19 >= brickRect.x || 
                                         ballPositionX + 1  <=  brickRect.x + brickRect.width  ){
                                    ballDirX = - ballDirX;
                                }else{
                                    ballDirY = - ballDirY;
                                }
                                //creates a label that says when this code executes, get out of the 
                                //outer loop
                                break A;
                            }
                         }
                      }
                    }
                //end of the code with an error in it


                //makes sure the ball is moving
                ballPositionX += ballDirX;
                ballPositionY += ballDirY;

                //makes sure the ball isn't going beyond the borders
                if(ballPositionX < 0){
                    ballDirX = -ballDirX;
                }
                if(ballPositionY < 0){
                    ballDirY = -ballDirY;
                }
                //think this code doesn't work
                if(ballPositionX > 670){
                    ballDirX = -ballDirX;
                }
            }

            repaint();

        }
```

Here's the `setBrickValue` method:

```
    public void setBrickValue(int value, int row, int col){     
          map [row] [col] = value;  
        }
```

All help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

PS: If anybody would like to see the whole code (400ish lines), just tell me and I would upload it.

Comment: Have you thought, instead of using `intersect` method -- just map ball location to the brick coordinate on map in checks? This will remove need of going through all map, you'll just check if there is a brick in the map at balls position, this will make debugging easier and you'll just launch debugger and step through this loop watching variables, understanding how code actually works. Like `int ballMapX = (ballX-80)/MGobj.brickWidth`

Comment: I will try to do it this way. I suppose I could find more tutorials online about how this method is best executed. Thank you! :)

Comment: I managed to fix my problem by fixing those 4 lines: `int brickX = j * MGobj.brickWidth + 80; int brickY = i * MGobj.brickHeight + 50;` and `if( ballPositionX + 19 <= brickRect.x || 
                                         ballPositionX + 1  >=  brickRect.x + brickRect.width  ){`